# HTML5 pattern phone number In Egypt

Tags: html, regex

What regex do I need to put into `pattern` to make sure the inputted number start with "011", "012" or "010" and then 8 digits?
Example of wanted output:

> 012 XXXXXXXX
>
> 011 XXXXXXXX
>
> 010 XXXXXXXX

Note : X is any number from [0-9].

```
<input type="number" pattern="" required />
```

Comment: Your question is "What regex do I need to put into `pattern` to make sure the inputted number satisfies these constraints", yes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
<input type="tel" pattern="^01[0-2]\d{1,8}$" required />
```

If you need or want only one space you can also use:

`^01[0-2]\s\d{1,8}$`

EDIT:

As Roland has mentioned, you should also use type="tel", instead of number, otherwise the pattern will be ignored.

Comment: i think <input type="tel"> work only for safari

    http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

this is true or false ?

Answer (score 3):

This is the regular expression for mobile phone numbers in Egypt for the 4 major Service providers:

```
^01[0-2,5]{1}[0-9]{8}$
```

Comment: you don't need use {1} because default group is 1 char

Answer (score 1):

```
<input pattern="^(00201|\+201|01)[0-2,5]{1}[0-9]{8}$" >
```

1. This validates if the number starts with the country code `00201`, `+201`, or `01`
2. Validate that the telecoms company prefix is correct
3. validate if contain 7 numbers after its, and in the end of the number.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this `Regexp`:

```
/^01[0125][0-9]{8}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

in 2021 i will add new mobile providers 015

```
^01[0-2,5]\d{8}$
```